# Deploy Entity Framework Code first database not generating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, ef-code-first, webdeploy

I'm trying to deploy with Visual Studio 2019 a web api using Entity Framework Code first with migrations. The deployment works fines because my test request returns what I expect. However, the database doesn't seem to generate because I get an error when trying to get all the employees.

In my Web.config, my connection string looks like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ProjetCVC_DB" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial 
     catalog=ProjetCVC_DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

LocalDB is installed on the server

Here is my employee controller :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using ProjetCVC_API.Models;

namespace ProjetCVC_API.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Employees")]
    public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
    private DataContext _db = new DataContext();

    // GET: api/Employees
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return _db.Employees.Include(e => e.Roles);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok("Hello world!");
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return _db.Employees.Count(e => e.EmployeeID == id) > 0;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the result of my Test request :
[image]

Here is the result of my GetEmployees request from client :
[image]

From server : 
[image]

Here is my Web deploy publish Profile :
[image]
[image]

I would like the database to generate and apply all the migrations. I tried a lot of things, but I can't make it work.

Comment: How are you applying the migration to the database?  Also, you should inject the DataContext into your controller.  You should not instantiate it directly as you are.

Comment: See Apply Migrations at Runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime

Comment: @BrianM I think the Execute Code First Migrations checkbox in the Publish menu is supposed to run the migrations. If not, how can I apply them then? And why is it bad to instantiate the DataContext directly, it's automatically generated like that?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm not using EF Core but EF 6.4

Comment: @Mr-RandomQC - did you create a migration for your database to create it?  Also, if you instantiate your DataContext like that, you make it impossible to unit test your controller.  If you inject it, you can now mock the DataContext in the unit tests.